# MyEclipse keeps crashing after a minute of opening

Tags: myeclipse

Can somebody help me with resolving this issue? MyEclipse keeps crashing after opening my workspace.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to some plugin signing issues with older releases of MyEclipse. Please go to [this notice](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/myeclipse-2017-integrity-check-error-unexpected-termination/) for solutions.

Sorry I didn't see this earlier but it would be better to go to the MyEclipse support forums for a faster resolution to issues.

Comment: I did try 2018 and found too many issues with cloning from my git repo and then went back to 2017 stable version -2 for my work. Its working now in 2017 stable ver 2.